# Convert AMRWB IO Raw speech data to wav file

Tags: codec, pcm, amr

I am trying to convert AMRWB IO raw data to wav file.

The format for the raw data is

Packet length followed by speech data.

THe raw file is given to the EVS Codec (Floating Point) 3GPP TS26.443 encoder. The encoded file is given to the  AMR Wideband Codec 3GPP TS26.190 / ITU-T G.722.2 decoder using the itu format. The decoded file is given to the audacity software to cenvert it into a audio file but the audio file contains only noise.

The EVS Codec (Floating Point) 3GPP TS26.443 repo can be found at https://github.com/wanglihe/clean-evs

The AMR Wideband Codec 3GPP TS26.190 / ITU-T G.722.2 repo can be found at https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.722.2-201712-I!AnnC/en

The command used for encoding using the EVS codec is as follows
./EVS_cod 23850 16 AMRWB-IO-i0.16k AMRWB-IO-i0.192

The command used for decoding using AMR Wideband Codec is as follows
./decoder -itu AMRWB-IO-i0.192 AMRWB-IO-i0

After decoding the AMRWB-IO-i0 file is given to the audacity software to convert it into a audio file but the audio file contains only noise.